# Read formatted text input

Tags: c, text-files

I have a txt file from which I want to take input. It looks like this:

```
1   33,3434   34,562 ...
2   24,354    55,234 ...
....
```

seperated by tabs. There is also a tab as well as a newline at the end of each line.
I want to read numbers seperated by commas, as integers, in an array of linked list. Here is the structure:

```
struct node
{
    int vertex;
    int dist;
    struct node* next;
};
```

I have tried following methods:

```
1. Using fgets and strtok:
    fgets(s,300,fp)
    while(strtok(...)!=NULL)
```

This reads one extra something(\n,\r) at the end which creates problems.

```
2. Using fscanf:
    for(i=1;i<=SIZE;i++)
    {
        fscanf(f,"%d",&i);//once per iteration
        fscanf(f,"%d,%d",&a,&b);//while it returns 2
    }
```

This method reads a single line only. I can't figure out how to move the pointer to next line.

```
3. Using fgets and sscanf:
    for(i=1;i<=SIZE;i++)
    {
        fgets(s,300,f);
        sscanf(s,"%d",&c);//once in a loop
        sscanf(s,"%d,%d",&a,&b)//while it returns 2
    }
```

However sscanf's pointer doesn't move as sscanf is called again. I cannot read a line in one go as the number of elements in each line varies

Comment: There's a tab as well as a newline?

Comment: If you can parse a single line, all you need is to read a file line-by-line and then parse that. Have you tried that? One approach actually seemed promising, only that you forgot to strip the final newline, which then confused further parsing.

Comment: Is each number that is separated by a comma a vertex/dist pair?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt In strtok method, I tried using if(strcmp("\n",..) break; but it didn't work. Then I tried reading the last character of file and compared it in place of \n. It worked for 14 lines and then gave SegFault. So I'm not really sure what's at the end of each line. Tab and newline are definitely there.

Comment: @Al.Sal Yes to both. And before someone asks it, yes that's a coursera assignment

Comment: Okay, last one. Is 1...2...3... part of the data?

Comment: @Al.Sal Yes It is a part of data.

Comment: `for (int i=0; s[i]!=0; ++i) {printf("%02x ", s[i]); }` Use this code to get the byte values for the string you have. Do this to the string you are reading and you should find out what exactly you have.

Comment: 09 0d 0a is at the end of each line. I think 09='\t', 0d=CR 0a=LF.

Comment: Somehow, comparing with end of line's hex value worked. `if(temp[0]==0x0d) break;` where temp is returned by strtok. Thanks for the help.

Comment: One issue: `sscanf("%d",c);` --> `sscanf(s, "%d",c);`

Comment: @chux sorry mistyped here. I'll edit it to correct it. There may be more syntax errors while typing but it's not an issue in the code. Believe me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 3rd method is closest, try this modification.  Use `"%n"` to know where parsing stopped.

Note: review notes on use of `sscanf()`.

```
for(i=1; i<=SIZE; i++) {
  char s[300];
  if (fgets(s, sizeof s,f) == NULL) HandleEarlyEOF();

  int a,b,c;
  char *p = s;
  int n;
  if (sscanf(p, "%d%n", &c, &n) != 1) HandleMissingIndex();
  p += n;

 while (sscanf(p, "%d ,%d%n", &a, &b, &n) == 2) {
    Use(a,b,c);
    p += n;
  }   
}
```